# How to access model properties inside a controller computed property

Tags: ember.js

I am fairly new in Emberjs. I have the following scenario:

```
App.Message = DS.Model.extend
  value: DS.attr('string')

App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  isAvailable: null

  isShowButton: (->
    #I want to check a property of each obj in the template's each loop below
    console.log @get('value') #but << this outputs `undefined`

    if @get('value') == 'test' and isAvailable
      return true
    else
      return false
  ).property('isAvailable', 'model.value')
```

And on my template:

```
{{#each controller}}
  {{value}}
  <!-- THE BUTTON ONLY SHOWS UP WHEN THE CONDITION ABOVE SATISFIES -->
  {{#if controller.isShowButton}}
    <input value='Test Button' type="submit">
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Route:

```
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model)->
    controller.set('model', @store.find('message'))
```

What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See my answer below, you need to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate your array, value doesn't exist on the collection, it exists on each item in the collection, there is a nice helper for that `getEach` which returns the value off each item in the array, it's used like this (pardon my coffeescript)

```
App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  isAvailable: null
  isShowButton: (->
    #I want to check a property of each obj in the template's each loop below
    //console.log @get('value') #but << this outputs `undefined`
    values = @getEach('value')
    console.log values
    outerValue = false
    values.forEach(function(value){
      if value == 'test' and isAvailable
        outerValue = true
      //else
        //  I'm not sure if they all have to be test 
    });
    return outerValue
  ).property('isAvailable', 'model.@each.value')
```

And your route should really use the model hook

```
CcChat.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params)->
    return @store.find('message')
```

#### Update

If you are trying to create a computed property for each item in the controller you'll want to use the `itemController`, which specifies the controller to use for each item in the array.

```
 App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
      itemController: 'foo'
      isAvailable: null

 App.FooController = Em.ObjectController.extend
      needs: ['messages'] 
      isShowButton: (->
        return @get('value') === 'test' && @get('controllers.messages.isAvailable')
      ).property('controllers.messages.isAvailable', 'value')
```

Comment: Hmm the button is showing in every 'each' object now. But I can access the values now, although it's 'all values' and not the 'each object' in the 'handlebar each loop'

Comment: Move the button outside of the each :)  Are you just wanting to show it in each item depending on the value of each item, or is it a group item based on all of the values?

Comment: I'm not sure what or where isAvailable lives, so I wrote it up as if it lived on the messages controller, it may need to live on the item controller, but you can change that as needed

Comment: Yes. I want the button to appear only each time value == test. Yes isAvailable is boolean property of messagesController. Okay I'll try using this itemController :)

Comment: Yey finally! Thank you so much! :)